# What kind of cloth and cleaner do the people who work at the Apple store use to clean MacBooks?

Tags: ipad, mac, macbook-pro, macos

I have a MacBook and an iPad and see dirt and fingerprints all over it.

What kind of cleaner do the people in the Apple store use to clean all the Macs and iPads on display?

I figure that anything strong enough to handle that abuse (being in a store used by so many people) should be good enough for use at home.

Comment: Really, does it matter? Any microfibre cloth will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [iKlear](https://www.klearscreen.com/detail.aspx?ID=11) on my Retina MBP. I can recommend them, however, they are a bit expensive. I have seen workers clean MBP's screens with it(though not in an official Apple store, but in a store that sells only Mac related products).

Answer (score 1):

They probably use some kind of wipes. There are wipes sold especially for computer screens. Maybe Apple-branded ones.

I use the dilute rubbing alcohol with which I clean my eyeglasses and the corner of a clean cotton dishtowel.

Apple says to use just water, but I figure, you only go around once.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use anything with alcohol or solvent on the iPad, iPod touch, or iPhone, they have an oleo-phobic coating which repels the oil from ones hands. Any solvent, alcohol..... will reduce the life of the coating. Below is the link for cleaning apples products.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3226#ipads